# Java Crypto trying to encrypt a file

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I am trying to encrypt a file called "AES.KEY". I'm not quite sure what I am doing wrong. I have to encrypt a file with an AES key (which i've created) and this is then stored in the file "AES.KEY"

When I run my code I am getting the following error message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider
> supporting acYb01wFX3pFk1xkouoCqFc6t9BBelPHgRnKXhQCnKo=
> at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:571)
> at WannaCry.encryptKeyFile(WannaCry.java:89)
> at WannaCry.main(WannaCry.java:84)

My question says I am to encrypt this Key with a RSA public key which is the variable
NOTE:

- Variable skey = my AES Key
  Here is my code for the program

  ```
  ///CODE ABOVE
     IvParameterSpec iv =  generateIv();
     EncryptFile(skey, iv, file);
      //CREATE AES.Key file
     File file2 =  createKeyFile("aes.key");
      encryptKeyFile(skey, pubKey, file2, iv);
      }
  private static void encryptKeyFile(SecretKey sk, PublicKey pubKey, File file, 
     IvParameterSpec iv) {
    String encodedKey = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(sk.getEncoded());
    byte[] b = encodedKey.getBytes();
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(encodedKey);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey, iv);
    byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(b);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
      fos.write(cipherText);
      fos.close();
     }
  ```

What am I doing wrong? If anyone knows I would be very grateful.
Cheers Jeff

Comment: You should pass the name / id of the encryption algorithm to `Cipher.getInstance`, not the key.

Comment: Thank you I got it working now!

Comment: Great. But you are for some reason base 64 encoding before you wrap the key, which is unnecessary. Tthe fact that it works doesn't necessarily mean it is right or secure.